# Unable to determine compiler to use - the abstract compiler specification is missing from this Xcode installation

Tags: xcode, warnings, rule

Hi I have iMac with OS X Yosemite version 10.10.3 and I've installed the last Xcode 6.3 beta 2 with Swift 1.2 and when I try to Run the App I receive: 
Check dependencies
Unable to determine compiler to use - the abstract compiler specification is missing from this Xcode installation.

and everytime when I open my project with Xcode I receive a warning:
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/Bogdan-iMac/Desktop/My App/My App/My_App.xcdatamodel' of type wrapper for architecture x86_64
and I have to open Build Phases in Compile Sources I have to remove My_App.xcdatamodel and add it again to prevent the warning

Link in Apple Dev Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/263126

Comment: Just so everyone sees this: **cold reboot your machine**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem here. The error disappeared after upgrading Yosemite to version 10.10.3 (14D87h) from today.

Comment: The new compiler compiles for 5 seconds 4000 lines of code the old compiler that I used wants 2 minutes.. :D

Comment: did version 10.10.3 (14D87h) help?

Comment: Sorry for my noobish question, but are we concluding that we can only run B2 on a beta OS?

Comment: Ronald yes it helps, thank you! Maury I don't know ask it officially.

Comment: *sigh* Ok, where do I download the beta. Yes, I am a registered developer. There goes my bandwidth cap, thanks Apple.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action - From here you can download Xcode 6.3 beta 2 with Swift 1.2

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Restart helped, even under Yosemite 10.10.2

Comment: I can confirm this fixed it for me too. rolleyes

Answer (score 1):

restart XCode-Beta helps me! And my Yosemite is 10.10.3 Xcode is Version 6.3 (6D532l)