# Xcode 7 Unable to determine compiler to use

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I get the following errors in Xcode 7 when opening my OS X app:

`Unable to determine compiler to use - the abstract compiler specification is missing from this Xcode installation.`

and

`Unexpected tool settings, missing default value for VFS output path`

I've tried rebooting as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685180/unable-to-determine-compiler-to-use-the-abstract-compiler-specification-is-mis) post suggests, but to no avail. 
I'm running OS X 10.10.4

**EDIT** Here is a screenshot:
[image: error]

Comment: What is the TOOLCHAINS build setting evaluating to for your target?

Comment: Good question, i don't even know what the tool chain does? @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia

Comment: It basically sets the compilr to use.  It was more important during the transition from gcc to clang, and maybe you have an old stale value from the past.  Also, maybe your Xcode install is incomplete (got canceled half way?)

Comment: The problem seemed to have fixed it self. I was playing around with some frameworks (adding / removing them), and now the error is gone. Thanks for you help though!

Answer (score 0):

Very lucky.

And I got this error this morning.

Everything worked fine until yesterday and I didn´t change any settings. Just GUI changes. I switched between Yosemite an ELCap and the error occurs on both systems.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when Xcode location was in /Application/Subfolder/Xcode.app

After moving to /Application problem is gone.