# XCode 8.3.1 Missing default C++ ObjectiveC compiler. Cannot build projects

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, build-error

After upgrading to XCode 8.3.1 I am getting an error:

```
Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0' selected for architecture 'x86_64'
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

Suggestions to set the compiler as default does not help, since the XCode does not see default compiler:

[image: screenshot that there is no default compiler]

Is there any solution?

Upd:

Actually, there is the compiler in the system:

[image: terminal screenshot]

Upd 2:

And one more screenshot with errors explained

[image: errors screenshot]

Update 3:

I created new XCode project from scratch (Single view) and it does not compile.

[here is github repo without .gitignore](https://github.com/ruan65/test-iOs-project.git)

So all project files should be there

And screenshot that shows values of GCC_VERSION= is empty

[image: screenshot of error]

Update 4:

Updating to Version 8.3.2 (8E2002) does not help,
Unfortunately ((

Comment: Try to run `xcrun clang++ -v`?

Comment: @kennytm for xcrun clang++ -v the output is the same as on the screenshot above for command cpp --version

Comment: Accoding to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762717/xcode-7-unable-to-determine-compiler-to-use, try rebooting the machine?

Comment: @kennytm reboot does not help, unfortunately. (I even reinstalled XCode and the problem is there still)

Comment: Can you post a link to a minimal example showing the issue?

Comment: @shallowThought I've updated the question accordingly...

Comment: Update Xcode and hopefully, the error will go away. version 8.3.2 has some bug fixes for this

Comment: try updating to new version (released today - 19/04/2017). i think it has fixed this bug.

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos Version 8.3.2 (8E2002) did not help (( The problem is still there and looks as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that has helped me was the total erasing the mac, installing the MacOS Sierra and after, XCode fresh installation.

Now I am able to compile projects - the gcc compiler has become visible and acceptable to XCode build tool.

(:very sad:)

Answer (score 0):

This likely indicates that one of Xcode's caches is corrupt. Try the following:

1) Quit Xcode

2) Open terminal

3) Run the following command:

`` rm -r `getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR`/com.apple.DeveloperTools ``

4) Relaunch Xcode

If you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate if you could file a bug about this at https://bugreport.apple.com. Please attach a build log showing the error you're seeing now, and please also indicate whether the steps I've given you solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, Rick. The applying the script you've suggested does not help. The problem is still there. I've opened the bug report (31646017)

Comment: It may be that your installation of Xcode is corrupt, then rather than it just being a corrupt cache. Can you try reinstalling Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it already, the post I created after that.
I completely deleted old version using CleanMyMac app and installed Xcode via Apple store. It, unfortunately, did not help me.